# is there any command manager for Laravel artisan

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

i have few commands in my laravel production app.

```
php artisan serve

php artisan queue:work

php artisan roulette:color

php artisan roulette:even
```

i am using vpn with ubuntu custom host

right now i am making 4 different screen for running these commands which is run forever

but sometime few crash don't know why and i have to find again which screen have crashed command

i am seeking is there any manager that can manage my commands easily

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to make 4 different screens, just run:

```
nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon &
```

this will prevent the command exiting when you log out.
the trailing ampersand (&) causes process starts in the background, so you can continue to use the shell and do not have to wait until the script is finished.

you can run any shell command in the background by adding the `&` to the end:

```
nohup php artisan serve &
```

### Installing Supervisor

Supervisor is a process monitor for the Linux operating system, and will automatically restart your `queue:work` process if it fails. To install Supervisor on Ubuntu, you may use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

### Configuring Supervisor

create `laravel-worker.conf` in the `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` directory:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/laravel-example/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/laravel-example//storage/logs/supervisord.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

you can see [Supervisor: A Process Control System](http://supervisord.org/) and [Supervisor Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#supervisor-configuration) in Laravel doc for more  info

Answer (score 1):

Supervisor is a process monitor for the Linux operating system, and will automatically restart your `queue:work` process if it fails or keep any other command active. To install Supervisor on Ubuntu, you may use the following command:
sudo apt-get install supervisor.

**Configuring Supervisor**

Supervisor configuration files are typically stored in the `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` directory. Within this directory, you may create any number of configuration files that instruct supervisor how your processes should be monitored. For example, let's create a `laravel-worker.conf` file that starts and monitors a `queue:work` process:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/path/to/you/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/path/to/you/app.com/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

In this example, the `numprocs` directive will instruct Supervisor to run 8 `queue:work` processes and monitor all of them, automatically restarting them if they fail. You should change the `queue:work sqs` portion of the `command` directive to reflect your desired queue connection.

**Starting Supervisor**

Once the configuration file has been created, you may update the Supervisor configuration and start the processes using the following commands:

```
sudo supervisorctl reread

sudo supervisorctl update

sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
```

For more information on Supervisor, consult the [Supervisor documentation](http://supervisord.org/index.html).